# How to append array with UITextField input?

Tags: arrays, swift, button, uitextfield, label

I have an assignment to make a calculator to calculate the average number of given inputs. 
I will need to accept and display number entered in the `range` between 0 and 100 (‘ADD’ button). And calculate and display the average.

There is a `UITextField` where i enter the numbers , then press the ADD button to display it into a `label/textview` (im not sure which to use).

The numbers should be appended into an array so as to use the `averageOf()` function.

I've tried displaying the numbers but the `label` replace the new number instead of adding it. Im very new to swift and not sure how to code to accept only a certain range of number.

My text field :

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtInput: UITextField!
```

ADD button :

```
@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let testScore = txtInput.text
        scoreDisplay.text = testScore
    }
```

The output/display of number should be , example , `40, 23.6, 98.2, 74.4`
What i get is just the replacement of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You should append using `+=` instead of `=` (which replace the whole value)

```
scoreDisplay.text += ", \(testScore)"
scoreDisplay.text = scoreDisplay.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ,"))
```

Trimming is used to remove the first `,` in your string.

### Edit

Since `text` property of a `UILabel` is `Optional<String>` you actually cannot use `+=`. So:

```
scoreDisplay.text = scoreDisplay.text ?? "" + ", \(testScore)"
scoreDisplay.text = scoreDisplay.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet(charactersIn: " ,"))
```

Comment: I did that an got an error " Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context " . Not sure what it means and how to fix it?

Comment: @KHY it's because `text` property is optional, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found the problem. 
Both scoreDisplay.text and testScore.text are optional, so you **must make sure they have a value.**

```
@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
   guard let testScore = txtInput.text, let scoreDisplay = scoreDisplay.text else  { return }
   scoreDisplay.text = scoreDisplay + testScore
  }
```

Also, if you want to add ", " in the middle of each number:

```
@IBAction func btnAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
   guard let testScore = txtInput.text, let scoreDisplay = scoreDisplay.text else  { return }
   scoreDisplay.text = "\(scoreDisplay), \(testScore)"
  }
```

PD: The = only remplace your string with other, the += append a new string.

Comment: It gives an error " Expression type '@lvalue String?' is ambiguous without more context "
Do u know how i can add the input number from tex field into an array at the same time?

Comment: What type of data is your array?
[String] , [Int], [Double] ... ?

Comment: Data type is Double

Comment: Try this in the func where you want to add the input into an array: 

`if let testScore = Double(txtInput.text) {
  theNameOfYourArray.append(testScore)
}`

Comment: You ask if txtInput.text can converse into a double, and if is possible, append into your array.